# db.engine.echo is true, even though SQLALCHEMY_ECHO is false

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy is logging all queries although I have `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False` (and verified in debug). Further investigation shows that `db.engine.echo` is `True`.

Env-wise, `FLASK_ENV = development`, `FLASK_DEBUG = True`. However changing these settings does not have any impact on the observed behaviour. I.e. I can observe the same with `FLASK_ENV = production` and `FLASK_DEBUG = False`.

Relevant libraries: Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4, SQLAlchemy==1.3.18, GeoAlchemy2==0.7.0

Anyone got ideas what I can check maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your debug to `False` and also for`SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS`, you need to set it `False` as well